# Building different networkx graphs in a for loop

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, networkx

I have a big pandas dataframe from which I have to extract several networks, considering each time a subset of the dataframe. These graphs will be bipartite, so there will be two groups of nodes (two columns in the dataset), nodes_x and nodes_y. I'd like to build the graphs in a loop, instead of doing it manually. How can I assign recursively a name to each graph?

Piece of code to explain:

```
import pandas as pd
import networkx as nx

df=pd.read_csv('my_dataframe')

sub_list=df.nodes_y.unique()

for item in sub_list:
    sub_df=df[df['nodes_y']==item]
    sG_*item*=nx.Graph() #here I'd like to assign a name to the network 
                         #recursively based on the subset of the dataframe
    sG_*item*.add_nodes_from(sub_df['nodes_x'])
    sG_*item*.add_nodes_from(sub_df['nodes_y'])
##rest of the code
```

Above all, is this a feasible and advisable way to operate? Are there better solutions to my problem?

Comment: Use a dictionary instead of new variable names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's try using a dictionary instead of new variables:

```
import pandas as pd
import networkx as nx

df=pd.read_csv('my_dataframe')

sub_list=df.nodes_y.unique()
sg_dict = {}


for item in sub_list:
    sub_df=df[df['nodes_y']==item]
    sG_dict[item]=nx.Graph() #here I'd like to assign a name to the network 
                         #recursively based on the subset of the dataframe
    sG_dict[item].add_nodes_from(sub_df['nodes_x'])
    sG_dict[item].add_nodes_from(sub_df['nodes_y'])
##rest of the code
```

Comment: Nice and easy. Thanks :)

Comment: Further question: if I do this manually for one item of `sub_list` and then I check if this object is equal to the corresponding dictionary item, I get a `False`. Is this normal?

Comment: I'll explain myself better. If I perform the operations within the for loop I wrote in my question for a single `item` of `sub_list`(let's call it X), I get a single graph. This graph should be equal to sG_dict[X], am I right?

Comment: Alright, so I do not understand why I get a `False` when I equal the two objects

Comment: Hrm... What does your compare statement look like? And, you create a new question with some sample data showing that?

Comment: With G being the graph I create outside the for loop (related to item X), the statement looks like `sG_dict[X]==G`. I'll create the new question as soon as I have time, since I can't use the real data because it's sensible. I'll try to reproduce this with some mock up data.

Comment: oh thanks. Well, I get a `False` statement also with `nx.is_isomorphic()`, so there must be something wrong.